# Where can I find the keystore file?

Tags: java, ant, jar, jar-signing

I created a keystore using `keytool`, but the thing is, we're using a JDK remotely ( and I don't have write priviledges on the server ). 
I noticed that ant has a `keystore` attribute, and I would like to pass that along to the `signjar` task.

Is it possible to add the keystore into the version control repository, and use it from there?
For example, something like this:

```
<signjar jar="my.jar" alias="myAlias" 
    keyStore="path/to/keystore" storepass="somePass"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. In fact - we do this where I work. We have a keystore on a glassfish web domain and we sign jars with it via the URL to it.

Hope this helps.